# A performant and robust way to reset multiple files to its original state (TDD)

Tags: design, unit-testing, testing, tdd, integration-testing

In our automated Java tests, we sometimes encounter issues, such as:

- Test `A` creates a custom file `A.sh`, that is then added on classpath
- Automated testsuite cleanup does not know about random file `A.sh`, and does not clean it
- Test `Z` fails because it so happens that `A.sh` has no influence on all other tests but causes failure in this particular test

These issues are incredibly hard to debug and to follow, because test `A` could have been written 3 years ago by people who left 2.5 years ago. I wonder, how would you implement a robust and also performant check of multiple files?

I have a following workflow in mind:

- Before test: Save state of all files in the watched directory. Note that the number of files we truly care about is ~30 in around 2-3 directories.
- During test: Test modifies them however it wants.
- After test: The testsuite checks the state of all configurations. If the state matches beforeTest state, we move on. If not, we put it back to its original state.

In my mind, this is similar to:

- `git add . && git commit -m "Original state"`
- Test modifies whatever it needs to
- `git reset --hard && git clean -fd`

I am almost tempted to literally use git for this, i.e. initialize repository with original state and then simply reset the state. Is there a better way?

As it stands, we currently copy all the config files before testsuite (the original state) and after each test, we copy them back (restore original state), regardless of which configs changed. This suffers from:

1. Being slow because all the configs are written onto the disk regardless of which files were used
2. Mainly, if there is a new file that we did not account for, because it is a custom file that does not come with the server, the testsuite does not know to remove the file.

Is there any elegant solution to this problem that you'd recommend? Is using git something that would make you track me down 5 years later when I'm not at the company anymore, with an axe to grind?

Other possible solutions:

- Spin up a small DB where I'd save all the files with hashsums at the beginning of a testsuite and check all files against the DB?

  - If the hashsums match, we don't worry about it.
  - If the hashsum is not found in the DB but the name is, restore it
  - Else, delete it

My worry is how performant this would be, though if we're talking about in-memory DB, could be OK. Also, another worry of mine would be that this could be the most fragile part of the testsuite. Afterall, tests should be as independent as possible.

Note that we use one testsuite for up to 5 versions of our software, so the set of ~30 files and ~2 directories differs, and hence has to be somehow cached/remembered at the beginning of each firing of the testsuite.

## Constraints

- We are talking about testsuite only. I cannot make changes to how many configuration files we have to watch
- We are talking about running the testsuite on multiple architectures; the solution at the *very* least has to be available for Linux, Windows, and Solaris (hence Java)
- Using a different language from Java is OK, but has to be very well reasoned. I don't mind writing the solution in a separate small little C binary and cross-compiling it, but this adds a large amount of complexity and as such, it is not a decision to be taken lightly.

Comment: `Is there any elegant solution to this problem that you'd recommend?`  -- Yes.  Write more unit tests and fewer integration tests.  What's that?  You say you'd have to change your code to make that happen?  ***Exactly.*** You'd have to change it to be more testable.

Comment: The solutions you are considering are a band aid – a quick fix that hides the problem but doesn't solve it. This might be a good tradeoff. Or it might end up making any problems even more difficult to debug. The only long-term solution is to fix your tests to never touch files outside of a temp-dir that can be wiped after each run.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Imho that is not a sound advice. There are complex systems at play that have to integrate together (imagine an application server with Hibernate, DB in the cloud, and a simple app using both). Unit test tests each of the components perfectly, but my job is not to re-test Hibernate; my job is to ensure that Hibernate works with our software.

Comment: I would not make the process dependend from a *specific* VCS like git. Keep your input files in some directory where they stay untouched. When you expect the test to modify them, copy them into a working directory before the test starts (and clean the working directory beforehand), then run the test on that working directory. When the test is complete, let the working directory where it is, giving you a chance to inspect it in case the test failed. For each new test, use a different working directory.

Comment: @amon Agreed. However, I want to enforce this rule programmatically. Is that not a sound reasoning? Because it's not that people don't want to clean after their tests, it's that they sometimes don't realize what's left behind.

Comment: No need to "clean afterwards". Clean *before*, automatically.

Comment: @pydoge Then that is a bug in your tests. Consider adding a self-test like “assert that the working directory is empty after the tests complete”. If that check fails, mark the test run as failed and fix the bug. I'd rather not have a separate software guess which files should be reverted to which state.

Comment: You're right.  Your job is not to re-test Hibernate.  But instead of including Hibernate in your unit tests, you should be excluding it using mocks and stubs.

Comment: @amon: why should the working directory be empty after the test is complete? Makes no sense to me. Makes it only hard to find errors afterwards.

Comment: @amon That sounds reasonable, but does it account for a random `a.sh`? You'd build a list of expected files at the beginning with their hash sums, and then have a check that checks that the sums match && that there is no new name? I'll think about this one...

Comment: @DocBrown I agree that dependency on git is a code smell to me. Hence this question. We do something similar to that. It is quite inefficient because we want to have one parent directory with all the files (so that we don't have to unzip and copy everything onto the harddrive before every test), and so the conf directory is given. It is possible to change the conf directory, but includes copying a lot more files than just a conf... Maybe that could be implemented with symlinks, though that could be a problem on some archs (like older Windows).

Comment: @RobertHarvey This is then your opinion. I respect it, but with all due respect, do not think it's applicable to my personal situation.

Comment: @pydoge: when unzipping files is a bottleneck, you better leave them unzipped. When copying files is a bottleneck, use a fast SSD or a memdisk, and try to make your files smaller. I guess symlinks are available in NTFS for more than 15 years, you don't need to support Win98, I guess? However, Symlinks won't solve your problem, since when you start modifying a "linked" file, you actually modify the file in the original place as well, that is not what you want here.

Comment: Whether you think you are or not, you're testing Hibernate when you do integration testing with it.  Your choices are to live with the complexity of that integration, or section it off using stubs or mocks.      You can try to corral that complexity by piling on additional complexity in the form of more techniques and software, but at some point, I think you have to ask yourself whether or not you're building a house of cards.

Comment: "I will not write a module complex enough to need testing that also touches the file system directly".  Write that a thousand times on a chalk board and it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use a memory-based file system that can be re-created at the start of each test.

In the Java ecosystem, JimFs is very competent for this. It does require injection of the file system into the application code, but this can often be hidden by use the `Path` object.

Another approach is to use underlying file system capabilities, such as mount points.